# Is a read to a volatile field happens before every subsequent write?

Tags: java, volatile

Java Concurrency in Practice says (in JMM chapter)
Volatile variable rule: a write to a volatile field happens before every subsequent read of that same field

My question is : A read to a volatile field happens before any/every subsequent write on that same field ??

Answer (score 1):

Theoretically it is a one way relationship. The exhaustive list of happens-before relationships is defined in the [JLS #17.4.5](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4.5) and only includes `hb(volatile write, volatile read)`.

However it is likely that it is implemented both ways by the JVM (it is the case for hotspot).